# Coded UI Test Excel Connection String Directory Error

Tags: excel, directory, connection-string, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to use excel with my coded-ui test but my connection string is not working. Can you help me on this? I'm kind a nuub on this :)
Ok, here - > my data directory is C:\ (directly in C drive)
and my connection string is

`[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=C:\\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]`

This works perfectly. But i want my files to be in "D:\TestProjects\Coded2\DataFiles\Data1.xls" and i couldn't do it. getting some errors and test-failing.

How should i write my data directory?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What `[DataSource...]` string did you use and what *exactly* were the errors?

Comment: I did use this:

[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=D:\TestProjects\Coded2\DataFiles\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]

and getting error: Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Are you using VS2010 or 2012 (or 2013 even)?

There's a data connection wizard you can use in VS2010 that will create the string for you. If you're using 2012 you'll have to code it yourself - I'm not sure how it works in 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that works and that is in the question is

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=C:\\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

The version that fails is shown in a comment, it is

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=D:\TestProjects\Coded2\DataFiles\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=79‌​0;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

The significant difference is that backslashes `\` are doubled in the one that works because they are escape characters in strings. C# is taking each backslash plus the following letter as an escape sequence. So the file name `D:\TestProjects\Coded2\DataFiles\Data1.xls` has `\T`, `\C`, `\D` and `\D` and the compiler is saying that one or more of them is not recognised.

You can also write C# strings with a leading `@` that means backslashes mean themselves. So the non working version should work if written as

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", @"Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=D:\TestProjects\Coded2\DataFiles\Data1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=79‌​0;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

Comment: @Aurora If the question has been answered then would you please mark it as answered, otherwise people may wonder what else is wanted by the question.